# Sharing data - custom controls

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have problem with sharing data between custom controls. I have one parent custom control who have 3 childrens. In first child I have combobox where I choose from 3 options. After change in that combobox I want to send picked option to 2 others children. How i can do this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the value from whatever the combobox is bound to. e.g. if it's set with `value=#{document1.foo}`, get the value with `document1.getItemValueString("foo")`, if it's `value="#{viewScope.foo}"` get the value with `viewScope.foo`.

There's rarely a valid need to use `getComponent()` for editable components.